# How to Flexbox into a specific way?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to seperate my divs into something like the image below using flexbox but i'm not sure how to do it. Do I need to use absolute positions for it or does flexbox have a way to approach it without too much issue?

[image: Image Link]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Left side : margin-right: auto. Using column wrap would make the left side.

Comment: ideally this is a css-grid area, see https://jsfiddle.net/rfa1kgt5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

What you have described is definitely possible. I have provided a rough outline of how it can be achieved below. [This link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) should fill in the blanks for you. Essentially you need a container which has the `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` attributes. Then the children inside the container will need the `flex-direction` and `flex-grow` attributes set appropriately.

You should also check [this site](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) to see if flexbox is supported by the browsers you are targeting.

**edit** You will also have to set the [order property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property) if you want to reorder the HTML elements - thanks to @BugsArePeopleToo who brought this up in a comment.

Comment: I thought the question implied a particular HTML structure where the numbers indicate their order in the markup, no?

Comment: This is handled by the [order property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property) which is supported by flexbox and allows people to do weird and wonderful things.The order property is mentioned in the first link that I provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you use flexbox for this layout, you'll need a few extra wrapper divs: one to contain all five divs, one to contain divs 1 & 4, and one to contain divs 2 & 5. It may also be worth it to try CSS grid, which is built for this kind of thing without wrapper divs.